# Calculating more than one value from select option dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, pdo

I wanna ask how to calculate more than one option from values in dropdown.

I will add here simple html code and function from PDO functions. What I want is to calculate values in  `<div id="RightBox">` which are moved there from `<div id="LeftBox">` throught javascript buttons and then count their values with calculation after exploding them with `$value = explode('|', $_GET['service'])`  When I explodes these values I wanna to take `. $vysledek["Service_price"] .` this value from function Typ() and count all of these values by this `$calculation = (2 * $height * ($lenght + $width) + ($lenght+ $width)) * $value[1];` pattern. I have it working for just one selected ( the last one ) But I wanna to make it work for all so that `$calculation` pattern will be used for each type of service and then all of the calculations will be numbered and then to echo final price. I really don't know how to do it maybe you can help me. Thank you.

HTML :

```
<div id="Calkulator">
  <form>
    <h2>Calculator</h2>
    <table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="lenght">Lenght of room in m2: </label></td>
          <td><input type="number" class="text_field small" id="lenght_of_room" min="1" name="lenght"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="width">Width of room in m2: </label></td>
          <td><input type="number" class="text_field small" id="width_of_room" min="1" name="width"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="height">Height of room in m2: </label></td>
          <td><input type="number" class="text_field small" id="height_of_room" min="1" name="height"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="typ">Service type: </label></td>
            <td>            
              <div id="LeftBox">
                <select id="leftValues" size="8" multiple>
                <?php
                  require_once 'funkce.php';
                  $database = new Database();
                  $database->Typ();  
               ?>
               </select>
             </div>
             <div id="Buttons">
               <input type="button" id="btnLeft" value="&lt;&lt;" />
               <input type="button" id="btnRight" value="&gt;&gt;" />
             </div>
             <div id="RightBox">
               <select id="rightValues" name="service" size="8" multiple>
               </select>
             </div>
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Count">
            <div class="clear"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <?php
      $height = $_GET[height];
      $lenght = $_GET[lenght];
      $width = $_GET[width];
      $value = explode('|', $_GET['service']);
      var_dump($value);
      $calculation = (2 * $height * ($lenght + $width) + ($lenght+ $width)) * $value[1];  
      echo "<p>Price: $calculation Kč</p>";
    ?>       

    </form>
  </div>      
</div>
```

PDO PHP : Function Typ

```
public function Typ() {
  try {      
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT Service_name , Service_price FROM Service_type");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach ($result as $vysledek ){
      echo '<option value="'  . $vysledek["Service_name"] . "|"  . $vysledek["Service_price"] . '">' . $vysledek["Service_name"] . '</option>';
    }  
  } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
  $this->conn = null; 
}
```

Comment: do you mean, you wanna sum values selected under selection box?

Comment: I wanna sum values which are added into RightBox so all the values in right box. These types of services which are added in right box then when user choose them have some different price. which is in function Typ() represented by  `.$vysledek["Service_price"] . ` from database. and then use calculate pattern for each of the Service type and then count all of the prices into one final price.

Comment: yup, then check my answer below, and very importantly you need to use `JS` to make every right sided option to be selected, means with attribute `selected`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you went wrong in naming your select element here.

Change `<select id="rightValues" name="service" size="8" multiple></select>` to `<select id="rightValues" name="service[]" size="8" multiple></select>`

`name="service"` to `name="service[]"`

and you could use `array_sum()` to sum your selected values under `service` selection box.

```
$servicePriceSum = array_sum($_GET["service"]);
```

know more about `array_sum()` : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php

> **NOTE:** wherever you have multiple selection of options just add up `[]`
>   in name attribute.

**UPDATED : to get only prices from `serviceName.'|'.servicePrice`**

```
$getSelectServices  = $_GET["service"];
$servChargeArr      = array();
foreach($getSelectServices as $serviceDet) {
    $expServiceDet  = explode("|", $serviceDet);
    $servChargeArr[]= &$expServiceDet[1];
}
$servTotal          = array_sum($servChargeArr);
echo $servTotal;
```

use the above code to get your required result.

Comment: Well I tried this one but still how to use this array_sum when my option collects of Name of service and Price of service..Thats why I use explode

Comment: You can check this [link]http://www.mape.8u.cz/Kalkulator.php?delka_mistnosti=10&sirka_mistnosti=10&vyska_mistnosti=10&sluzba=%C5%A1t%C4%9Brkov%C3%A1n%C3%AD+a+%C5%A1tukov%C3%A1n%C3%AD+om%C3%ADtek%7C65

Comment: @Lukas.K you didn't add `[]` in name attribute, that is what my answer says. add it, and it will surely work.

Comment: Added that but still it just returns int(0) .. I think u can't use that like that because of `echo '<option value="'  . $vysledek["Service_name"] . "|"  . $vysledek["Service_price"] . '">' . $vysledek["Service_name"] . '</option>';` I think u might just don't get me cause I wanna to make calculating in something like for statement where I go through all of the selected services in rightbox and then make calculation for each of the service with calculation pattern and then just number all of the counted prices of each service.

Comment: first tell me, did you get all the selected records in your PHP file?

Comment: Yes I think I get all of the records when I confirm button with submit. I see all of the names of services and prices in link  [http://www.mape.8u.cz/Kalkulator.php?delka_mistnosti=10&sirka_mistnosti=10&vyska_mistnosti=10&sluzba%5B%5D=%C5%A1t%C4%9Brkov%C3%A1n%C3%AD+a+%C5%A1tukov%C3%A1n%C3%AD+om%C3%ADtek%7C65&sluzba%5B%5D=mal%C3%AD%C5%99sk%C3%A9+n%C3%A1t%C4%9Bry+b%C3%ADl%C3%A9%2C+barevn%C3%A9%2C+t%C3%B3novan%C3%A9%7C19&sluzba%5B%5D=malby+pomoc%C3%AD+vysokotlak%C3%A9+techniky+AIRLESS%7C19] All of the services which I added into right box are there.

Comment: Everything now works, Thank you very much I really appreciated your help. You are awesome :)